# How can i use less than or equal to for a string?

Tags: java, android

```
mUserBalance.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    int lim = 100;

                    //final String user_bal = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue());

                    //balance from firebase database
                    String user_bal = (String) dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue();

                    if (user_bal.){
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, user_bal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "not enough balance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: You might want to go over a Java tutorial before doing Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_bal is a String data type and hence <= is not preferred. If you sure the value of this variable will be numbers (integer as variable lim is of type int, used for compare) , then try this

```
 String user_bal = (String) dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue();
    int userBalance = Integer.parseInt(user_bal);

    if (userBalance  <= lim){
        // do something
    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, " NOt enough balance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


    }else{
       // do something
    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, user_bal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
```

Comment: Depending on firebase data, the balance could also be gotten as a double / integer on its own

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @cricket_007: you need to define whether it should be double/integer. To ease the comparison done next. The data is stored in string form. So convert string to double/integer and make lim match the same data type.

Comment: I'm just saying `("balance").getValue(Integer.class);` might be possible

Comment: these are the data types firebase support
String
Long
Double
Boolean
Map<String, Object>
List<Object>

i doubt you can use integer. In that case you can use double and <= , no need for extra parsing(as in case of string)

Comment: int user_bal = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue());

Comment: @tannitanna int user_bal = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue());                                                  like that?

Comment: @Santana Ortega: yes that is OK if value is string , but cricket_007 said he would prefer ("balance").getValue(Integer.class);